# how to insert a correct table in latex?

Tags: tables

When I compile my LaTeX file the left line of the table is missing. What is the proper solution for this problem? Any one please guide me. The picture is shown below.

My Command

```
 \begin{table}[h]                           
 \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Tm:YLF crystal}} \\ \hline

     Crystal phase    &   Tetragonal                \\ \hline
     Chemical formula &   $Tm:YLiF_{4}$             \\ \hline          
     Melting point    &   $1075^{\hspace{0.03in}\circ}$C  \\ \hline
     Density          &   $7.27 g/cm^{3}$           \\ \hline
     Site Symmetry of $Y^{3+}$  &   S4              \\ \hline
     Thermal conductivity       &   0.6 W/cm. K     \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Tm:YLF crystal properties}
    \label{tab:msg1}                            

\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Without seeing your code, I think you might be using the command `\multicolumn` here for the columns. In that case, maybe try `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Tm:YLF crystal}`. If that doesnt help, please post a Minimal Working Example which shows us the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem and this also ensures that the solution actually works for you.

Comment: #Runar Trollet ,,,   i sent my command

Comment: Have you tried his suggestion?

Comment: @RunarTrollet - You should make your comment into an answer.

Comment: don't use math italic for multi-letter identifiers, especially units such as `cm`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing a `|` in your header: `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Tm:YLF crystal}}`.

I have in the code below fixed the issue, but also added a copy of your table with some suggestions on possible improvements for both your reader and yourself.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}% More proffesional look of tables.
\usepackage{siunitx}% An awesome package for typesetting and manipulation numbers and units.
\usepackage{caption}% Better control over caption
\usepackage{lipsum}% Example text

\newcommand{\tableHeader}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]                           
 \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Tm:YLF crystal}} \\ \hline

     Crystal phase    &   Tetragonal                \\ \hline
     Chemical formula &   $Tm:YLiF_{4}$             \\ \hline          
     Melting point    &   $1075^{\hspace{0.03in}\circ}$C  \\ \hline
     Density          &   $7.27 g/cm^{3}$           \\ \hline
     Site Symmetry of $Y^{3+}$  &   S4              \\ \hline
     Thermal conductivity       &   0.6 W/cm. K     \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Tm:YLF crystal properties}
    \label{tab:msg1}                            

\end{table}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[h]                           
 \centering
    \caption{Tm:YLF crystal properties}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\tableHeader{Tm:YLF crystal}} \\
    \midrule

     Crystal phase    &   Tetragonal                \\ 
     Chemical formula &   \(\mathrm{Tm:YLiF_{4}}\)             \\         
     Melting point    &   \SI{1075}{\celsius} \\ 
     Density          &   \SI{7,27}{\gram\per\cubic\centi\metre}          \\ 
     Site Symmetry of \(Y^{3+}\)  &   S4              \\
     Thermal conductivity       &   \SI{0,6}{\watt\per\centi\metre\per\kelvin}    \\ 

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \label{tab:msg1}                            

\end{table}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: no problem. if you want to ping somebody here, use `@` in front of their names.